Why is my new starter not working
2006 Ford mustang V6
So my car was having trouble starting at some point almost sounding like the starter teeth weren't engaging with the flywheel. I didn't care to take the car to someone so I just replaced the starter with a new one. I put the wires on the starter. Reconnected the battery and tried to start it. Absolutely nothing happened when I try to start it. It's getting power and both wires are connected. I don't know what to do.

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Did you test the starter before you put it in? Could be a bad starter from the parts store.

Also, do you hear any clicking when you turn the key?

What wires went to which starter terminals? Is the battery fully charged? Main ground connections between battery, chassis and engine block clean and free of corrosion?

